# How do I remove an extension from LibreOffice 3?

Tags: libreoffice, uninstall, extension

I click the remove button, but nothing happens...

Is there any way to remove an extension? I have 3 to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove an extension using the same way that you used to install it, i.e.:

- If you downloaded it from the web, then the remove button should work.
- If you installed it from the Software Centre, then it's installed system-wide (for all users) and you should remove it using the Software Centre.

Comment: This answer was not helpful. Even when downloaded from the web, the 'Remove' button does not remove the extension.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and manage to solve it by removing the corresponding files in
`/home/$USER/.config/libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache` is one folder and one file with the same name you will found what it is once you open the folder to view its contents to find the extensions

#### Example:

```
luyjgau6.tmp_ #(This one is the folder) 
luyjgau6.tmp  #(This one the file)
```

***The names will be different in your system.***